# How to retain backslash in apache ant replaceregexp task?

Tags: ant

I have a property in application.properties as below

`application.generalsettings.environmentname.blacklist=value_to_replace`

And I have a task in build.xml as below

```
<replaceregexp file="application.properties" match="value_to_replace" replace="\"" byline="true"/>
```

However it giving me output like below:

`application.generalsettings.environmentname.blacklist="`

Instead of
`application.generalsettings.environmentname.blacklist=\"`

So is there any flag in replaceregexp to retain backslash as shown in above output ?

Comment: Are you sure you actually need the back slash? Double quotes don't need to be escaped in java-style properties. If you know the name of the property you're trying to change the value of, you could just use Ant's `propertyfile` task.

Answer (score 0):

(I get XML parsing errors with your task as-is.)

I think this should work for you:

```
replace="\\\\&quot;"
```

At the moment your backslash is escaping the double quote after it.
You need to escape the backslash "twice", once so the XML can be parsed correctly, the second time so the substitution works, hence the 4 successive slashes above.  `&quot;` is the XML entity for a double quote.

I'm not sure why you XML parser is happy to parse "\"", seems very forgiving!